# How can i disable date picker icon 

Tags: javascript

I have a field called AppDate and it should get disabled conditionally 
the field is getting disabled but the date picker icon is not getting disable, hence though i disable AppDate Field users are able to change the date

```
<hx:inputHelperDatePicker firstDay="1" rendered="true" styleClass="inputText_DatePicker" disabled/>

<f:convertDateTime dateStyle="short" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
    <hx:inputHelperDatePicker firstDay="1" rendered="true" styleClass="inputText_DatePicker" disabled/>
    <hx:inputHelperAssist errorClass="inputText_Error" promptCharacter="_" />
    </h:inputText></td>
```

Comment: Are you refering to JQuery's Datepicker plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to JQuery's datepicker plug-in, you can disable/destr0y the datepicker:

```
//disable
$("yourdateinput").datepicker( 'disable' ); 

//destroy if you not going to need it anymore
$("yourdateinput").datepicker( 'destroy' );
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#methods

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea which date picker you are using. So I'll speak generally, you should probably 'unbind' the click/mouse[up|down] event from the "icon" and rebind it back when you enable the input textbox